# how to use $month using aggregation in spring data mongo db

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

I am using mongodb.I have to use aggregation query for $date in my spring data mongo db. This is my User collection.

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(70289),
    "_class" : "com.samepinch.domain.user.User",
    "age" : 25,
    "roles" : [
        "ROLE_MODERATOR",
        "ROLE_USER"
    ],
    "firstName" : "Abhi",
    "lastName" : "Saini",
    "email" : "abhisheksn138@gmail.com",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-12-04T12:29:57.604Z"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2016-02-10T06:23:13.314Z")
}
```

this is my mongodb query

```
 db.users.aggregate([{ $project : { month_joined : { $month : "$createdDate" } } } ,{ $group : { _id : {month_joined:"$month_joined"} , number : { $sum : 1 } } },{ $sort : { "_id.month_joined" : 1 } }])
```

The query giving me the desired result as:

```
{ "_id" : { "month_joined" : 1 }, "number" : 19 }
{ "_id" : { "month_joined" : 2 }, "number" : 7 }
{ "_id" : { "month_joined" : 9 }, "number" : 16 }
{ "_id" : { "month_joined" : 10 }, "number" : 12 }
{ "_id" : { "month_joined" : 11 }, "number" : 11 }
{ "_id" : { "month_joined" : 12 }, "number" : 13 }
```

Now I have to write this query in spring data mongodb using mongotemplate. I am new in using aggregation.Is their is any easy way to use it. Please help

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try projecting the fields first by using the **[SpEL `andExpression`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.examples.example5)** in the projection operation and then group by the new fields in the group operation:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    project("id").andExpression("month(createdDate)").as("month_joined"),
    group("month_joined").count().as("number"),
    project("number").and("month_joined").previousOperation(),
    sort(ASC, "number")
);

AggregationResults<JoinCount> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, 
                                                     "collectionName", JoinCount.class);
List<JoinCount> joinCount = results.getMappedResults();
```

---

In the above a new aggregation via the **`newAggregation`** static factory method is created to which you pass a list of aggregation operations. These aggregate operations define the aggregation pipeline of your Aggregation.

In the first step you project the fields from the input collection by using the **[SpEL `andExpression`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.examples.example5)** with the project operation.

In the second step you use the group operation to define a group for each `"month_joined"`-value for which you aggregate the occurrence count via the `count()` aggregation operator and collect the result in a new field called `"number"`.

As a third step select the field `"number"` and create an alias for the `_id`-field generated from the previous group operation (hence the call to `previousOperation()`) with the name `"month_joined"`.

As the fourth step sort the resulting list of the grouped `month_joined` documents by their occurrence count in ascending order via the sort operation.

Finally call the **`aggregate()`** Method on the MongoTemplate in order to let MongoDB perform the actual aggregation operation with the created Aggregation as an argument.

---

To filter documents getting in the pipeline for the current year, you need to project a new field that holds the year part of the date and after the project step then issue a match operator, something like

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    project("id")
        .andExpression("month(createdDate)").as("month_joined")
        .andExpression("year(createdDate)").as("year"),
    match(Criteria.where("year").is(2016)),
    group("month_joined").count().as("number"),
    project("number").and("month_joined").previousOperation(),
    sort(ASC, "number")
);

AggregationResults<JoinCount> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, 
                                                     "collectionName", JoinCount.class);
List<JoinCount> joinCount = results.getMappedResults();
```

Comment: when i am using project(). andExpression(). It is asking me for andExpression(String expression,Object Params). I dont know how to use it according to your answer ?

Comment: Did you try `.andExpression("month(createdDate)")` instead of `.andExpression("month(date)")` as had previously shown?

Comment: Actually .andExpression() is asking for two arguments i.e andExpression(String expression,Object Params). I am confusing what to pass in it.

Comment: Thanx #chridam its work for me.  :) But what should i do if i want to count users for each month only for a current year ?

Comment: Then you need to first filter the documents getting into the group pipeline by introducing a `match()` pipeline before the `group()` which filters documents by the current year. I would be more than glad to answer this on a separate question since updating the above answer will be very misleading to people who come along and see that answers provided do not match what you have asked. The general case here is one question one answer. Please post it separately

Comment: #chridam i have asked separate question on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029246/how-to-get-result-by-year-in-mongodb. Give me any suggestion if u know.

Comment: This is what i am trying before group operation.                                           AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where(
    "year(createdDate)").is("2016"));

Comment: Waaooow its work . Thank you so much #chridam for giving your time and updating the answer. :)

Comment: No problem @Abhisheksaini, always happy to help :)

Comment: how can i do this if my date is stored as string

Answer (score 3):

Since 2.1 your can use [DateOperators.Month](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/DateOperators.Month.html).

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    project("id").and(DateOperators.Month.month("createdDate")).as("month_joined"),
    group("month_joined").count().as("number"),
    project("number").and("month_joined").previousOperation(),
    sort(ASC, "number")
);
```

Comment: need $ before createDate, otherwise exception occurs: can't convert from BSON type string to Date.